# React bootstrap - how to make navBar with 100vh height when in mobile

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

When I expand the `navBar` by clicking the menu button, I want the `dropdown` has full height(`100vh` etc), the UI should be like this:
￼￼[image]

This is the current UI in mobile:
[image]

How can I do it?

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import Navbar from "react-bootstrap/Navbar";
import Nav from "react-bootstrap/Nav";
import NavDropdown from "react-bootstrap/NavDropdown";
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

import "./styles.scss";

function Header(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
        <Container>
          <Navbar.Brand href="#home">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
          <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
          <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
            <Nav className="me-auto">
              <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link href="#link">Link</Nav.Link>
              <NavDropdown title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
                <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">Action</NavDropdown.Item>
                <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">
                  Another action
                </NavDropdown.Item>
                <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">
                  Something
                </NavDropdown.Item>
                <NavDropdown.Divider />
                <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.4">
                  Separated link
                </NavDropdown.Item>
              </NavDropdown>
            </Nav>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Container>
      </Navbar>
      <div>content</div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

Codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-leftpad-3sejn?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

change css :

```css
@media(max-width:600px) {
  .navbar {
    min-height: 100vh;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
}
```

Comment: it's not working.

Comment: did you add !important?